# How do I tell my migration what column type to use?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 and PostGres 9.5.  I have created this migration

```
class CreateSearchCodeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :search_codes do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.references :address, index: true, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.index ["code"], name: "index_search_codes_on_code", unique: true, using: :btree
    end
  end
end
```

The ID column of the address table is not an integer though.  Maybe for that reason, I get the below error when I run the migration

```
== 20171011202623 CreateSearchCodeTable: migrating ============================
-- create_table(:search_codes)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  foreign key constraint "fk_rails_6bd9792e3b" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "address_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying.
: CREATE TABLE "search_codes" ("id" serial primary key, "code" character varying, "address_id" integer, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_6bd9792e3b"
FOREIGN KEY ("address_id")
  REFERENCES "addresses" ("id")
)
```

How do I instruct my migration to create my column with the same type as the referenced column?

Comment: I guess you have to do that manually 
`t.string :address_id`
and after the create table block
`add_foreign_key :seach_codes, :adresses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.references` delegates job to `add_reference` and this one accepts `:type` parameter. Judging from this, you *should* be able to do

```
t.references :address, type: :string, index: true, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :cascade
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Just tested this on a toy sqlite3-based project, it worked. Should "just work" on pg too.

---

> How do I instruct my migration to create my column with the same type as the referenced column?

If you meant to tell it to infer the type of the other column and have type of this one match it, then this is likely not possible. But you can always specify type explicitly.